# GameObject.CreatePrimitive() en Unity 2019.3.0.8a no funciona

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

Grosso modo, tengo una función cuya finalidad sería crear un nivel para un juego de plataformas que usa bastante CreatePrimitive.

La complicación viene cuando no sale nada en la consola, ni se crean los cubos en cuestión, pero si pongo mensajes de la consola, resulta que el código sí se ejecuta por completo.

Teniendo en cuenta que lenght está definido en otro lugar del código, y que este no sería el problema, he aquí el método en cuestión:

```
    void createLevel()
    {
        GameObject Gcube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        Gcube.transform.position = new Vector3(lenght+7, -4, 0);
        Gcube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 3, 1);
        Gcube.layer = 13;
        Gcube.name = "GoalCube";
    }
```

Tras indagar en la documentación del método que falla, he dado con que Unity anuncia que éste puede no funcionar durante el Runtime, y que la solución sería, copio de la web,

> CreatePrimitive may fail at runtime. This will happen if your project does not reference the following components: MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, and BoxCollider or SphereCollider at runtime. The recommended way to avoid this crash is to declare private properties of these types. The stripping system will recognise their use which include them in the build so will not delete these components.

Aun con esta descripción y solución al problema, creo que soy demasiado poco experimentado con el motor como para entender qué hacer.

Por ello, agradecería francamente desde traducciones y explicaciones hasta soluciones que hayan funcionado por propia experiencia, u orientación de si de verdad es este el error que me sucede a mí.
Cualquier tipo de información que necesiten, la daré lo mejor posible.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

no tienes necesariamente que crear la primitiva, puedes instanciar desde un prefabricado.

```
GameObject Gcube = Instantiate(objetoPrefab, transform);
Gcube.transform.position = new Vector3(lenght + 7, -4, 0);
Gcube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 3, 1);
Gcube.layer = 13;
Gcube.name = "GoalCube";
```

aunque  `GameObject a = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);` sigue funcionando